# Difference between controller definitions in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have two controllers I am trying to access one controller from other using `$injector`. 
when I define a controller (which i want to access) like following.

```
function monthlyController($scope){
//HUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
}
```

`$injector` works perfectly. but when i do this

```
app.controller("monthlyController", ['$scope',function($scope){
 //HUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
}]);
```

`$injector` doesnt work. gives error monthlyController is undefined.

so what exactly is the difference between

```
 function monthlyController($scope){
    //HUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    }
```

and

```
app.controller("monthlyController", ['$scope',function($scope){
     //HUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    }]);
```

NOTE- Other than `$injector` everything else works fine in either ways

Comment: I guess that Angular controllers cannot access functions outside of it, e.g. its like calling ()(); in JS

Comment: Can you show how you are using `monthlyController` and when the error occurs?

Comment: Inside another controller,ths code is write $injector.invoke(monthlyController, this, {$scope: $scope});

Comment: Why would you need to invoke your controller like that?

Comment: To access the variable of another controller.Stewie can you tell me how to access the variable in another controller.